# Updating images in resource section of an exe (in c#/C)

Tags: c#, resources, .net-2.0

I have few images embedded in my executable in resource section.
I followed these steps to create my executable:

1. Generated .resx file for all the images (.jpg) in a directory using some utility. The images are named image1.jpg, image2.jpg and so on.
2. created .resources file from .resx file using: `resgen myResource.resx`
3. Embedded the generated .resource file using /res flag as: `csc file.cs /res:myResource.resources`

4 I am accessing these images as:

```
ResourceManager resources = new ResourceManager("myResource", Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());

Image foo = (System.Drawing.Image)(resources.GetObject("image1"));
```

This all is working fine as expected. Now I want to change embedded images to some new images. This is what I am currently doing:

```
class foo
{
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        static extern IntPtr BeginUpdateResource(string pFileName, bool bDeleteExistingResources);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        static extern bool UpdateResource(IntPtr hUpdate, string lpType, string lpName, string wLanguage, Byte[] lpData, uint cbData);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        static extern bool EndUpdateResource(IntPtr hUpdate, bool fDiscard);


    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        IntPtr handle = BeginUpdateResource(args[0], false);

        if (handle.ToInt32() == 0)
            throw new Exception("File Not Found: " + fileName + " last err: " + Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());

        byte[] imgData = File.ReadAllBytes("SetupImage1.jpg");
        int fileSize = imgData.Length;

        Console.WriteLine("Updaing resources");
        if (UpdateResource(handle, "Image", "image1", "image1", imgData, (uint)fileSize))
        {
            EndUpdateResource(handle, false);
            Console.WriteLine("Update successfully");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Failed to update resource. err: {0}", Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());
        }
    }
}
```

The above code is adding a new resource for the specified image (inside `IMAGE` title with some random number, as seen in `Resource hacker`), but I want to modify the existing resource data for `image1`.

I am sure that I am calling `UpdateResource` with some invalid arguments.

Could any one help pointing that out?

I am using .NET version 2

Thank you,

Vikram

Comment: Cant you use linked resources? (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ht9h2dk8%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Comment: Two different animals.  A .resx file contains *managed* resources, they get embedded into the assembly manifest.  UpdateResource() only knows about unmanaged resources.  There's no mechanism to rebuild the assembly manifest beyond decompiling with ildasm.exe and recompiling with ilasm.exe.  Quite unpractical, especially compared to simply storing the jpegs files in a directory.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you are making a confusion between .NET resources, and Win32 resources. The resources you add embedding with the `/res` argument to `csc.exe` are .NET resources that you can successfully read using  you `ResourceManager` snippet code.

Win32 resources are another beast, that is not much "compatible" with the managed .NET world in general, athough you can indeed add them to a .NET exe using the `/win32Res` argument - note the subtle difference :-)

Now, if you want to modify embedded .NET resources, I don't think there are classes to do it in the framework itself, however you can use the [Mono.Cecil](http://www.mono-project.com/Cecil) library instead. There is an example that demonstrates this here: [C# – How to edit resource of an assembly?](http://rongchaua.net/blog/c-how-to-edit-resource-of-an-assembly/)

And if you want to modify embedded Win32 resources, you code needs some fixes, here is a slightly modified version of it, the most important difference lies in the declaration of `UpdateResource`:

```
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    static extern IntPtr BeginUpdateResource(string pFileName, bool bDeleteExistingResources);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    static extern bool UpdateResource(IntPtr hUpdate, string lpType, string lpName, short wLanguage, byte[] lpData, int cbData);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    static extern bool EndUpdateResource(IntPtr hUpdate, bool fDiscard);

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        IntPtr handle = BeginUpdateResource(args[0], false);
        if (handle == IntPtr.Zero)
            throw new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error()); // this will automatically throw an error with the appropriate human readable message

        try
        {
            byte[] imgData = File.ReadAllBytes("SetupImage1.jpg");

            if (!UpdateResource(handle, "Image", "image1", (short)CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture.LCID, imgData, imgData.Length))
                throw new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());
        }
        finally
        {
            EndUpdateResource(handle, false);
        }
    }
```

Comment: oops..silly me, didn't notice the /WIn32res flag. I will give it a try. Thank you.

Comment: Can making the `lpData` a `byte[]` instead of a `IntPtr` cause any trouble? Is it safe to do this in production code?

Comment: @Zuck - yes, you can, it depends what you have as input.

Comment: Thanks, do you know if it is possible to pass `lpType` a string and update an existing bitmap or icon? I tried updating a bitmap in a file using `lpType` as `"#2", "BITMAP", "RT_BITMAP"` etc. but instead of updating the bitmap, it created a new resource type named  `"#2", "BITMAP", "RT_BITMAP"` and added the new  resource under it. I have to overload `lpType` to type `IntPtr` and then pass it `new IntPtr(2)` for updating currently.

Comment: @Zuck - you should ask a full question

Answer (score 0):

This is impossible. You cant modify compiled file that you are running.

Comment: Are you sure? I can add new images and they are showing in resource section. I just can't use them because I don't know the identifier at run time. May be if I enumerate the list of available resources somehow, I can use them as well.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can add new images in run time but can't  update a resource that is essentially just held in memory.

If you add a resource in run time, it exists but I don't think it is compiled and therefore I don't think it is accessible to you.

Is there a reason you aren't using content instead?