# Add Image file resource to another project

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio-2012, embedded-resource, design-time

I want to add/update Image resources in a .NET project, so that when the application is compiled the images will be available at runtime.

Due to having a large amount of images in several locations I want to do this using a separate vb.net project.

The only way I can see to do this is to copy the image file to the `[Project]\Resources` folder and then edit the `[Project]\My Project\Resources.resx` to use this image file, but this seems a bit hacky and I'm not sure how fussy Visual Studio is about the format of the resx file.

Is there some other way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [ResourceWriter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xbx3z216.aspx) class to programmatically create a binary resource (.resources) file directly from code.

```
    using (ResourceWriter rw = new ResourceWriter(@".\CarResources.resources"))
    {
       Image im = Image.FromFile("C:\\sample.jpg");
        rw .AddResource("sample.jpg", im) 
      }
```

You can also use Resource File [Generator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ccec7sz1.aspx) (Resgen.exe) to create a .resources file from a text file or a .resx file.

Comment: I saw this, but can you edit a resource this way as well? (just for my own knowledge) :) - The OP's title and Question signify different things aswell.

Comment: @Rikoshay - apologies I have edited the title to hopefully be clearer

Comment: yes you can .. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/676312/modifying-resx-file-in-c-sharp or you need to open file in write mode and edit.

Comment: Very interesting, I'll keep this in mind, hope the  OP see's this

Comment: @MattWilko edited my answer with way to add image runtime.. also, there are lot of overload accepted by addResources method.

Answer (score 2):

Here you go :) Looking at your tags, there's no need for many words

Short sweet and down to the point paint explanation

[image]

Comment: Thanks - I was looking for a way to do this programmatically though!

Comment: ill go dig around, although I am not sure if this can be done from the application you want to change, since you EXE will be locked because your using it. Ill do some testing 1 moment

Comment: [Check this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9349784/updating-images-in-resource-section-of-an-exe-in-c-c#9446836) Roughly the same question - If that answers your question, why dont you finish close this question by marking this answer :)